# How can I remove this merge branch?

Tags: git, github

I have 2 branches: *beta* and *master*. `B1`, `B2` are the commits merged from the *beta* branch to *master*. How can remove the merged branch on *master* branch but still keep the commit `M3`?

```
e94af69 (HEAD -> master) M3
6c904b2 (beta) B2
cf5fffb B1
a7b50aa M2
eb077fe M1.
```

... to ...

```
e94af69 (HEAD -> master) M3
a7b50aa M2
eb077fe M1
```

Comment: One aspect of what you're asking for is impossible : commit `M3` won't have the same hash with a different ancestry.

Comment: Do you want to remove the branch or a commit?

Comment: Just the commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to **remove commits `B1` and `B2` from the *master* branch**, you can do an interactive rebase and drop them. According to your log, you can start the rebase at `HEAD~3` like this:

```sh
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

In the editor, write `d` / `drop` for commits `B1` and `B2`. And write `p` / `pick` for commit `M3`:

```
d cf5fffb B1
d 6c904b2 B2
pick e94af69 M3
```

After this, your history looks like the following graph. The commit hash of `M3` changed, since its parent is different. You see the commits `B1` and `B2` on the *beta* branch and no longer on *master*, while `M3` is still on *master*.

```
* cdd0cd5 (HEAD -> master) M3
| * 6c904b2 (beta) B2
| * cf5fffb B1
|/  
* a7b50aa M2
* eb077fe M1
```

---

If you just want to **remove the *beta* branch** but keep commits `B1` and `B2` on the *master* branch, you can simply delete the *beta* branch like this:

```sh
git branch -d beta
```

After this, your history looks like this:

```
* e94af69 (HEAD -> master) M3
* 6c904b2 B2
* cf5fffb B1
* a7b50aa M2
* eb077fe M1
```